Azure AD B2c authentication with Custom IDP
how to allow only a group of users from  azure active directory to sign up or sign in in azure ad b2c when using custom identity providers?
for example if I have configured Facebook as an Identity Provider in Azure AD B2c
only certain facebook users should be allowed to login or lets say only one group from facebook should be allowed to login and not all users should be allowed to login...
I am not finding any solution for this issue most of the resources only have information related to how an user flow/custom policy is created using custom idps (most popularly facebook). Help me with the requirement where we can restrict some users from the Active Directory of these custom IDP's and only allow some users for login.

If you add Facebook as an IDP, anyone with a Facebook account can log in.
If you want to restrict it, e.g., based on an attribute that Facebook passes, you will have to use custom policies and not allow some users to progress further, e.g., by showing a screen that says "You do not have permission."
